# Why can't I see `assets` folder in my Android package installation folder

Tags: android, storage, internal-storage

I'm browsing with DDMS my application's installation folder `/data/data/com.my.app` and I can't find where the assets folder is. I'm using it inside my application using URI `file:///android_assets/...`

[image]

Comment: @VicJordan - tag words should not be broken out in titles (that's what tags are for) however those fitting into the flow of the title are permitted.  In this case the topic is really Android - DDMS is just how it is being examined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't find where the assets folder is

That is because there is no assets folder on the device. The assets, like your resources, are packaged into the APK file. Assets are not unpacked as part of APK installation. `file:///android_asset/`, for those things that understand it, knows to look inside of the assets in your APK.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks! I thought that APK gets extracted on the device.